# Does fmt.Println receive any type of argument?

Tags: go

How does `fmt.Println` work? Why I can pass an `int` or a `string` to it?

How can I make the code below work?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func ln(a interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(a)
}

func main() {
    ln(123)
    ln("test")
}
```

Comment: Use `interface{}` to designate __any type__ , as per correction and answer.

Comment: If you edit your original question to code that works, your "how do I make this code work" question doesn't make sense anymore. Please leave the original code that you were stuck on so the question still makes sense in context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func ln(a interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(a)
}

func main() {
    ln(123)
    ln("test")
}
```

Output:

```
123
test
```

> [func Println](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println)
>
> ```
> func Println(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
> ```

The Go [`fmt`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/fmt/print.go) package uses the `reflect` package.